# combine rows into single cell

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I currently have a dataframe (df) like this:

```
name    info
alpha   foo,bar
alpha   bar,foo
beta    foo,bar
beta    bar,foo
beta    baz,qux
```

I'm looking to create a dataframe like this:

```
name    info
alpha   (foo,bar),(bar,foo)
beta    (foo,bar),(bar,foo),(baz,qux)
```

I'm getting close with groupby.apply(list). Eg.

`new_df=df.groupby('name')['info'].apply(list)`

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the output in the original dataframe format. (i.e with two columns (like the example)

I think I need `reset_index` and `unstack`? Appreciate any help!

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @Wen I want to create the dataframe like in the example I provided. But I'm missing one or two steps and I can't figure out what they are.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('name')['info'].apply(list))`? I feel like there's an easier way though

Comment: Is 'info' a single string or a list of strings in your input? And, in your output is that a single string or is that a list of tuples?

Comment: @ScottBoston Sorry, it's a list of strings. I should have mentioned.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh your suggestion works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following using `for` loop:

```
uniqnames = df.name.unique() # get unique names
newdata = []                 # data list for output dataframe
for u in uniqnames:          # for each unique name
    subdf = df[df.name == u] # get rows with this unique name
    s = ""
    for i in subdf['info']:
        s += "("+i+"),"      # join all info cells for that name
    newdata.append([u, s[:-1]]) # remove trailing comma from infos & add row to data list

newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=newdata, columns=['name','info'])
print(newdf)
```

Output is exactly as desired:

```
    name                           info
0  alpha            (foo,bar),(bar,foo)
1   beta  (foo,bar),(bar,foo),(baz,qux)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.assign(info='('+df['info']+')').groupby('name')['info'].apply(','.join).to_frame('info')
Out[267]: 
                                info
name                                
alpha            (foo,bar),(bar,foo)
beta   (foo,bar),(bar,foo),(baz,qux)



#df.assign(info='('+df['info']+')')# adding the ( and ) for your single string to match with the out put 
#groupby('name')# group by the name, you need merge info under the same name
#apply(','.join).to_frame('info') # this will combine each info into one string under the same group
```

Comment: This might be correct but would be nice to help the OP understand how you came to this. And what is "IIUC"?

Comment: @Nae add it  : -)

Comment: @dirkgroten add the explanation and IIUC means   If I understand correctly;

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['alpha']*2+['beta']*3,
                   'info':[['foo','bar'],['bar','foo'],
                           ['foo','bar'],['bar','foo'],
                           ['baz','qux']]})
print(df)
```

Inuput:

```
         info   name
0  [foo, bar]  alpha
1  [bar, foo]  alpha
2  [foo, bar]   beta
3  [bar, foo]   beta
4  [baz, qux]   beta
```

Now, groupby and apply then reset_index() to get back to dataframe:

```
new_df = df.groupby('name')['info'].apply(list)

new_df = new_df.reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    name                                  info
0  alpha              [[foo, bar], [bar, foo]]
1   beta  [[foo, bar], [bar, foo], [baz, qux]]
```